# Connect-SPOService

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

Hello I would like to know how can I fix this error on sharepoint power shell. 
[image]

Comment: Can you open the SharePoint admin portal URL and enter credentials to make sure they are correct? Also, remove Credentials parameter at the end and try manually typing them. See if it helps...

Comment: @Denis Molodtsov Yes it has work. however how do i get to see all users on powershell

Comment: @AY_91 I would recommend expanding your original question and credit to Denis for solving your initial query. Q&A in comments is best avoided, they are meant only to clarify.

Comment: I've copied the comment as an answer

Answer (score 2):

Can you open the SharePoint admin portal URL and enter credentials to make sure they are correct? Also, remove Credentials parameter at the end and try manually typing them.